# Questions list now improperly fit the home page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It seems that some recent change has caused the questions list on the homepage to be wider than its frame, causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear, and horizontal scrolling to be locked to that frame. Not a huge issue, but does cause some problems on my non-mobile touchscreen when trying to view the right-side bar.

Browser: Google Chrome v65 on Win 7, Win 10, and Android 6.0

[image]

Edit: It seems to work as expected if I disable the `#question-mini-list` CSS:

[image]

Comment: Able to reproduce on my Windows 7 laptop in Google Chrome, Firefox, and IE. Screen resolution 1920 x 1080.

Comment: Repro in MacOs, latest FF & Chrome

Comment: I see I was testing on the wrong page- Indeed I _am_ able to reproduce on Chrome 65.0.3325.181, Windows 7.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not able to reproduce on my Mac (10.12.6) in Chrome or Opera. Screen resolution 2880 x 1800.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Yes, we did some frontend code updates and it's a side-effect. I'm working on fix right now. Should be up tomorrow.

Comment: Appreciate it, @Paweł!

Comment: +0: +1 for the issue (just noticed it in all major browsers), -1 for not pointing it out with a red, freehand circle.

Comment: @Marco13 Good suggestion.

Comment: Hey! That freehand circle is fishy! And it's reproduced on W7 SP1, Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) _as stated before_.

Comment: I get the same on Firefox 57.0.1 (64 bit) on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thanks again for reporting. This was caused by some frontend code changes we've made. It should be fixed now.